# How to get value of texts added by css :after selector in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, selector

I want to get the text of a node but that node's text is constructed using css `::after` selector. Like

```
button::after {
  content: " - Remember this";
}
```

How do I get the text + " - Remember this" part in javascript? I tried `element.textContent` or `element.innerText` and neither of them work.